# A lot of views in a very short time

Tags: discussion, bug, moderation

I know this isn't one of the most trafficked SEs out there so found this to be a little out of the ordinary.

This post, [Get number of new emails from Microsoft Exchange server in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154839/get-number-of-new-emails-from-microsoft-exchange-server-in-sharepoint), has been asked a month ago and has 11,377 views currently.  If you look at the user's badges, it went from 1,000 views to 10,000 views in two days.  On top of that there are no up votes, no comments, and there wasn't an answer until this morning.

Does this seem odd to anyone else? The only thing I can think of is if that person has a popular blog and linked to their question, but I would think there would be something posted to it with all of that traffic.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see anything in the mod tools that would allow us to track this down. It is strange that the only post and answer the user has got a gold badge in a single day. I would hedge on the side of your argument that the user has a professional blog that is linking to it or happened to tweet it or something and got a ton of unique views.

This would have to be investigated from a SE employee.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole bunch of them:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a10000%20is%3aquestion%20score%3a0

Comment: I think that the point here was that he seem to have got 9k views in two days. Maybe there are other 10k questions, but it is the popularity boost speed that seems odd.

Comment: So maybee, whe should not classify @Danny's other question as a duplicate since it is now clear that there really are two different cases. I will reopen your forst post